# Rpm falls below idle when declutching at high rpm

Tags: rough-idle, carburetor, idle, old-cars

I've got this problem that I can't find the cause of.
When starting the engine, which goes very easily, it idles smoothly and stable, rising the rpm a bit still gives no problems. But when driving at high rpm speeds eg. on the highway, and i declutch rpm falls back to 300-400rpm. It's raised again to idle after a second or four. Sometimes i have to rev it up myself or it'll stall. There's no loss in power, pinging or whatever.
I've checked the following:

- Air leaks, there seem to be none.
- Mixture, it's set to around 4% CO or lambda 0.93 which is fine for this car ('76 Triumph TR7, SU carbs)
- Compression
- Ignition advance
- Carbs are synced and the dampers go up and down fine
- Just put new Duckhams Q 20W50 in it
- Drove with and without my PCV system connected to the carbs

The engine has been revised 6 months ago so everything is still clean and in good condition.(ie. nothing clogged or coked or whatever)
I've got a Facet performance fuel pump, and the fuelsystem also works fine.
It's equipped with stock needles and jets. As far as I know, i've checked
 everything. A friend of mine told me that although you can't see that, one or both dampers may not go down smooth enough as they should, causing this problem.
I doubt that though. As a side note: after the revisation it has as somewhat higher compression, it tends to run on a bit after shutdown. I don't suppose this has something to do with the problem. Suggestions or ideas anyone? Anything is much appreciated.
Cheers.

Comment: What is meant by "revisation"?

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 Sorry poor translation, the word I meant is revision or overhaul.

Comment: I don't know nearly as much about carb vehicles compared to FI, but does it have an idle control valve, or is it just a hole in the throttle plate?

Comment: @HariGanti It doesn't have an idle valve, but there's a overpressure valve in the throttlevalve itself, which opens under heavy manifold vacuum. Older carbs don't have those though.

Comment: I'd check that valve. It functions as a mechanical idle control valve, so if the spring is weak or you have a vacuum leak, it might not be opening. I'd suggest having a friend rev up the engine (or just pull the cable yourself), then suddenly release the throttle. See if that valve opens or not.

Comment: @HariGanti You can't see it, the damper piston in front of it blocks the view. But i'm replacing the throttlevalves with solid ones anyway, so let's hope the problem is fixed after.